# Need to link dynamically to an external URL in React

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I am trying to create a list of users and have an inline text link to each user's Facebook page. I need this link to be created dynamically from a database where the URL is saved as facebook.com/userpage.

This information is being saved from a form, so I'd prefer the user to not have to enter "http://www" when inputting the data.

Is it possible to use an href to do this? Something like this (which obviously does not work):

```
<a href="http://www.{user.facebook}">FB profile</a>
```

Comment: Seems like a text input element would be needed here, and perhaps when the the element receives focus and is empty, then add the `http://www.` so the user doesn't have to type it.  It might be helpful to include the dynamic <a> element to show what the linkable URL will actually look like, and be able to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using react router,

```
<Link to={"http://www.facebook.com/"+ user.facebook} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" />
```

Since React Router version 5.0.1, you can use

Comment: That worked when I changed the <Link> to an <a>. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template literal to interpolate the dynamic part of your url

```
<a href={`http://www.${user.facebook}`}>FB profile</a>
```